# Settings wont open in Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: gnome

I have Ubuntu installed on an iMac (Mid 2011) It has worked very well for 12 months or so.Now settings wont open. Tried to reinstall Gnome control centre and received the following message:

```
gnome-control-center: 
error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7: 
invalid ELF header.
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `uname -a; ldd $(which gnome-control-center); file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7; dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341369/edit).

Answer (score 1):

You may have library file corruption. To reinstall [its package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libopenjp2.so.7) use command below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libopenjp2-7
```

Comment: Many thanks indeed. That worked perfectly.